# GitLab openid-connect with Keycloak

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to use Keycloak as a login interface for authenticating to GitLab via Openid Connect ([GitLab instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/oidc.html)).

My Omnibus GitLab (running via Docker) config looks as follows.

```
        gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
          { 'name' => 'openid_connect',
            'label' => 'Keycloak',
            'args' => {
              'name' => 'openid_connect',
              'scope' => ['openid','profile'],
              'response_type' => 'code',
              'issuer' => '<url>',
              'discovery' => false,
              'client_auth_method' => 'basic',
              'send_scope_to_token_endpoint' => 'false',
              'client_options' => {
                'identifier' => 'gitlab',
                'secret' => '<secret>',
                'redirect_uri' => '<gitlab_url>/users/auth/openid_connect/callback'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

When clicking the login button however, I get a non-descriptive error message (shown below) in the logs (`gitlab/logs/gitlab-rails/production.log`).
It looks like the process completes in the first place (status code 200) but errors afterwards.
Does anyone have an idea if I misconfigured something or if the error is likely to be on GitLabs side?

[image]

```
Started POST "/gitlab/users/auth/openid_connect" for XY at 2020-10-13 14:17:05 +0000
Processing by Gitlab::RequestForgeryProtection::Controller#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 164)

RuntimeError (No Host Info):

lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:61:in `run'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:217:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:51:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:23:in `call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:60:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Answer (score 2):

Two issues caused this problem:

1. I used https instead of http for `redirect_uri` -> http is the correct choice
2. Because the root of my GitLab instance was not at the domain root but at `/gitlab`, auto-discovery failed and I had to set `authorization_endpoint`, `token_endpoint` and `userinfo_endpoint` manually. Also `discovery` needed to be turned off.